# how can i resolve the problem of 404 not found when i test a post request with postman

Tags: express, mongoose, multer

index.js code:

```
import express from "express"
import bodyParser from "body-parser"
import dotenv from  "dotenv"
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json())

dotenv.config()
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000
const mongo_url = process.env.MONGO_URL

mongoose.connect(mongo_url).then(()=>{
    console.log("Connected to database")
    app.listen(port,()=>{
        console.log(`app is running on port: ${port}`)
    })
}).catch((err)=>{
    console.error(`Error connecting to the database: ${err}`)
})
```

employee schema code :

```
import mongoose from "mongoose"
import validator from "validator"
const employeeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
nom:{type:String,
    required:[true,"Champ requis, veuillez le remplir"]},
prenom:{type:String,
        required:[true,"Champ requis veuillez le remplir"]},
email:{type:String,
       unique:true,
       required:[true,"Veuillez remplir votre email"],
        validate:function(v){if(!(validator.isEmail(v))){throw new Error("Email saisie est non valide")}}},
mot_de_passe:{type:String,required:[true,"Saisissez votre mot de passe"],
            minlength:8,
            maxlength:30,
        validate:function(v){if(this.mot_de_passe.length< 8 || this.mot_de_passe.length>30)throw new Error ("Mot de passe doit être entre 8 caractère et 30 caractères")},    
        validate:function(v){if(!(/[A-Z]/.test(v))) throw new Error("Mot de passe doit contenir au moins une lettre majuscule")},
        validate:function(v){if(!(/[0-9]/.test(v))) throw new Error("Mot de passe doit contenir au moins un chiffre")},
        validate:function(v){if(!(/[&#@{}-/*+=()"'_]/.test(v)))throw new Error("Mot de passe doit contenir au moins l'un des symboles suivants:&#@{}-/*+=()'_")}},
date_naissance:{type:Date,required:[true,"Champ requis, veuillez remplir votre date de naissance"],
                },
education:[{
    diplome:{type:String,required:[true,"Le champ est obligatoire"]},
    etablissement:{type:String,required:[true,"Le champ est obligatoire"]},
    annee_etude:{type:Number,required:[true,"Le champ est obligatoire"],
    enum:values[1900,1901,1902,1903,1904,1905,1906,1907,1908,1909,1910,1911,1912,1913,1914,1915,
        1916,1917,1918,1919,1920,1921,1922,1923,1924,1925,1926,1927,1928,1929,1930,1931,1932,
        1933,1934,1935,1936,1937,1938,1939,1940,1941,1942,1943,1944,1945,1946,1947,1948,1949,
        1950,1951,1952,1953,1954,1955,1956,1957,1958,1959,1960,1961,1962,1963,1964,1965,1966,
        1967,1968,1969,1970,1971,1972,1973,1974,1975,1976,1977,1978,1979,1980,1981,1982,1983,
        1984,1985,1986,1987,1988,1989,1990,1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000,
        2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,
        2018,2019,2020,2021,2022,2023,2024,2025,2026,2027,2028,2029,2030]
}
}],
Skills:{type:[String],required:[true, "Champ obligatoire"],minlength:1},
langues:[{
    langue: { type : String , required : true , enum:{values:["français","anglais","allemand","italien","espagnol","russe","turc","portugais"]} } , 
    niveaux : {type : String ,enum : ["A1","A2","B1","B2","C1","C2"]}
}],
realisation:[{
    date_realisation:{type:Date},
    description:{type:String,maxLength: 2000},
    intitule_projet: {type: String, maxLength: 100},
}],
telephone:{type:String,
    validate:function(v){if(!(validator.isMobilePhone(v)))throw new Error("Numéro de téléphone invalide")},
    required:[true,"Veuillez saisir votre numéro de téléphone"],
    unique:true},
photo_de_profil:{type:String},
cv:{type:String}    
})
export default mongoose.model('Employee',employeeSchema)
```

employeecontroller code:

```
import Employee from "../modules/employee"
import multer from "multer"

let cvfile=""
let photofile = ""

const photo_storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination:`${__dirname}/photoEmployee`,
    filename:(req,file,redirect)=>{
        let date = Date.now()
        let fl = date + '.'+file.mimetype.split('/')[1]
        redirect(null,fl)
        photofile = fl
    }
})
const photoUpload = multer({storage:photo_storage}).single('photo')
const cv_storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination:`${__dirname}/CVEmployee`,
    filename:(req,file,redirect)=>{
        let date = Date.now()
        let emp = new Employee()
        let fl = date+'.CV_'+emp.prenom+'_'+emp.nom+file.mimetype.split('/').pop()
        redirect(null,fl)
        cvfile = fl
    }
})
const cvUpload = multer({storage:cv_storage}).single('cv')
export const create = (async(req,res)=>{
    try{
        await photoUpload(req, res)
        await cvUpload(req, res)
        if (req.fileValidationError) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: req.fileValidationError });
          }
          const Employeedata = new Employee({
            ...req.body, // Données de l'employé depuis la requête
            photo: photofile, // Ajouter le nom de fichier de la photo
            cv: cvfile, // Ajouter le nom de fichier du CV
          });
        const {email} = Employeedata
        const EmployeeExist = await Employee.findOne({email})
        if(EmployeeExist){
            return res.status(400).json({message:"Employé est déja existe"})
        }
        const savedEmployee = await Employeedata.save() 
        res.status(200).json(savedEmployee)
    }
    catch(err){
        res.status(500).json({message:"Internal server error"})
    }
    finally{
        cvfile = ""
        photofile = ""
    }
})
```

employee router code :

```
import  express  from "express"
import { create } from "../controllers/employeeController"

const router = express.Router()
router.post('/create_employee',create)
 
export default router
```

the port in which the app work is 5001 and normally the url of the post request is : http://localhost:5001/create_employee i don't know why it returns 404 not found status

i want to check all the codes and what are the problems should i look for to pass my requests

Comment: where are you using the router?

Comment: when i tried to use the router in the index.js file the error is he can not import the router from the employeerouter file

Comment: it's the same thing

Answer (score 1):

When using [ES Modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) you need to remember to add the file extension if importing your own modules using relative or absolute paths. You don't need them for modules in the `node_modules` library. You also need to import your router and ideally mount it to the `app` you create.

Change the following:

**index.js**

```js
import express from "express"
import bodyParser from "body-parser"
import "dotenv/config"; //< Change to this
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import router from "./employeeRouter.js" //< import the router with the .js file extension

const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use('/', router); //< mount the router at the root '/' directory

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000
const mongo_url = process.env.MONGO_URL

mongoose.connect(mongo_url).then(()=>{
    console.log("Connected to database")
}).catch((err)=>{
    console.error(`Error connecting to the database: ${err}`)
});

// Move your app.listen out of the mongoose connection
// You want your server to start even if the mongoose connection fails
app.listen(port,()=>{
   console.log(`app is running on port: ${port}`)
})
```

**employeeRouter.js**

```js
import  express  from "express"
import { create } from "../controllers/employeeController.js" //< Need the .js extension

const router = express.Router()
router.post('/create_employee',create)
 
export default router
```

**Note**: you may need to look at other parts of your code where you are not adding the `.js` file extension when you import your modules.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `mongo_url = process.env.MONGO_URL` is receiving the url data

if so

check if the url received/create_employee really exists, because if it doesn't exist it will return 404 even though it tried to request a non-existing page.

Create an error middleware, it might help.

```
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
});
```

Make sure you are doing a POST in postman, because if you do a get for a route that only exists in post, it will also give a 404

Comment: it's the same thing

Comment: when i import the route file in the index.js file it shows me an error that he can not import it

Comment: Show me the error please

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell what error you get when you try to import the router in the `index.js` file because without it the app will not know that there is a `POST` route for `/create_employee`